# how exactly does LEFT OUTER JOIN in relational algebra work when there is no common attribute?

Tags: relational-algebra

for example suppose we have the two relations

R1(A,B)
R2(C,D)

also these are the tables

```
  A B
 a1 b1 
 a2 b2

 C  D
 c1 d1
 c2 d2
```

will the left outer join result be the following table?

```
  A   B  C  D 
  a1 b1 c1 d1
  a1 b1 c2 d2
  a2 b2 c1 d1
  a2 b2 c2 d2
```

we have no common attributes and this is why I don't include any NULL.

if this result is correct then it's essentially the same with the simple join and the cross join operator
am I wrong?

Comment: if there is no common column, you get a cross product of the two tables, as you show.

Comment: Your proposed output there is a `CROSS JOIN` or cartesian product...

Comment: hm..  can you do an outer join without specifying the fields used for joining??

Comment: yi_H, indeed in SQL you need to specify this, but in relational algebra you don't need to do this. I'm not 100% sure though.

Comment: x left join y on true is not x cross join y when exactly 1 of x or y is empty.

Comment: There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give operator definitions & your reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` is **always** done on some common column. For your example `CROSS JOIN` is the only one applicable - and it will give you exactly the result you provided.

Excrept (Chapter 5, *Relational Algebra*) from [*Rebeca M. Riordan: Designing Relational Database Systems, published by Microsoft Press*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966426.aspx):

> An outer join returns all the records returned by an inner join, plus
>   all the records from either or both of the other recordsets. The
>   missing ("unmatched") values will be Null.

Comment: If "the missing values will be null", then the result of your operation is not a relation, and therefore the thing that produces such a result is not an operator of the relational algebra.

Comment: x left join y on true is not x cross join y when exactly 1 of x or y is empty.

Comment: "`LEFT OUTER JOIN` is **always** done on some common column" False. This very post immediately goes on to contraidct itself by describing the (wrong) result for when there is no common column.

Answer (score 0):

`r1 LEFT JOIN r2` without a condition is equivalent to `r1 LEFT JOIN r2 ON (Empty)=(Empty)`. However, I don't think that you can issue in SQL a `r1 LEFT JOIN r2` without the `ON` part.

What you can do is to issue a `r1 NATURAL LEFT JOIN r2` (at least in MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE R1
( a int
, b int
) ;

INSERT INTO R1
  VALUES
  (1,1) ,
  (2,2) ;


CREATE TABLE R2
( c int
, d int
) ;

INSERT INTO R2
  VALUES
  (3,3) ,
  (4,4) ;

SELECT
      *
FROM 
      R1
  NATURAL LEFT JOIN 
      R2 ;
```

And the result is (correctly) the same as a `NATURAL INNER JOIN` and a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
a b c d
-------
1 1 3 3
1 1 4 4
2 2 3 3
2 2 4 4
```

Comment: What is "ON (Empty)=(Empty)" supposed to mean? In SQL variants that allow ON to be missing the meaning is ON 1=1. (If they have booleans we can say ON TRUE.)

Comment: x left join y on true is not x cross join y when exactly 1 of x or y is empty.

Comment: @philipxy you are 100% right about that. As this was 10 years ago, I frankly don't remember what I was thinking. I'll re-examine my answer and edit or delete.

Comment: Just give the definition of left join. Actually the question itself is just a(n unresearched) duplicate of, what is left join. But I haven't found a post about that for relational algebra. (Sadly the SQL question re left join vs inner join is accepted-answered atrociously with a zillion misconceived upvotes--also almost all other answers are atrocious, and all but one are flawed.) PS A standard comment of mine: "There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give operator definitions & your reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page."

Comment: The question is about relational algebra, but it was also unreasonably tagged with SQL, which I recently removed. SQL<>relational algebra.